# Programmatically writing CSS in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, vb.net, htmltextwriter

We're displaying objects within a web-page which have basic height and width properties. We can generate the HTML objects utilising the HtmlTextWriter object and plan to apply the Height and Width properties by referencing the object's ID in embedded css class at the top of the class.

```
#bob
{
   height: 20
   width: 20
}
```

...

```
<div id="bob"></div>
```

1) Firstly, is this a good approach or should we be considering another approach like inline css ?

2) There doesn't appear to be anything written in the surrort of rendering css within the .net framework. Does anyone know of anything which might be of assistance in rendering css notation with the .net framework. Is there an equivalent to `HtmlTextWriter` ?

3) Do you know of any tools which can be of assistance in generating css from code ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Keep CSS in .css, HTML in .html, C# in .cs

Comment: Hope this interests you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14033/Dynamic-CSS-Styling-in-ASP-NET-A-Flexible-Approach

Comment: the first question must be if the css must really be created dynamically. Means are the rules changing or every time the same, or do the ids and classnames of the object change? If not I see no reason why not to use a static external css file.

Comment: yeah sorry Sven ... probably didn't make it that clear. The CSS must be dynamically generated from the object properties.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do it in .net. But I am doing it in jquery as below. I hope this is someway useful.

```
$.rule("#bob {height:"+ht+"}").appendTo('style');
```

When this is generated then you can check in your dom that some css has been added to `style` element.

It is better than inline css. It works for the webpage which is displayed on the browser and not physically written to the file.

More info - [here](http://flesler.webs.com/jQuery.Rule/)

It works in IE8, FF and Chrome when I checked.

Comment: cheers ... looks interesting so will look into this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try almost not to use inline css and you can use a literal that has the css string in it, and let the htmlTextWriter write it.

Comment: with css string i mean the metatag <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" .... to include a css file in a page

Comment: Thanks ... found a page which explains how to link a css file at run time which is great, but I'm going to need a simple way to generate the css from the object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing out HTML, does one of the existing controls not provide what you need?

In general, CSS should be in a .css file.

It's not really possible to answer if this is a good approach since you haven't explained the intent of the code.

Comment: We're creating our own controls which do very specific things. I've now seen a method of programatically adding in a reference to the css file [link](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/how-to-add-css-programmatically-to.html) so this can be generated and linked during run time.